# Error in concurrent reading/saving of object in Transactional method

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, concurrency, locking

Facing problem in saving data with concurrent request thread. detail are as below:

1. Spring 3.0.5
2. Tomcat 1.6
3. Hibernate 3

Simulating the issue through sample application:

**DB Detail:**

1. user
2. userinfo

one **user** can contain multiple **userinfo** means there will oneToMany relationship between these table.

**Domain Classes**

**User class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5753658991436258019L;
    private Integer idUser;
    private String Name;    
    private Set<UserInfo> userInfos = new HashSet<UserInfo>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "iduser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Integer idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 256)
    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setName(String tenantName) {
        this.Name = tenantName;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserInfo> getUserInfos() {
        return userInfos;
    }

    public void setUserInfos(Set<UserInfo> userInfos) {
        this.userInfos = userInfos;
    }
}
```

**UserInfo class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userInfo")
public class UserInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5753658991436258019L;
    private Integer iduserInfo;
    private User user;
    private String address; 

    public UserInfo() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "iduserInfo", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIduserInfo() {
        return iduserInfo;
    }

    public void setIduserInfo(Integer iduserInfo) {
        this.iduserInfo = iduserInfo;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 256)
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

So what i am trying to do saving the **UserInfo** in db through hibernate but **before saving UserInfo** create **User** and try to fetch this from DB, if found then set in UserInfo object otherwise save it(User) then again fetch from DB (for **persistent** stat of User obejct). then set in UserInfo and save UserInfo object in DB.

**Note: This all works fine on sequential request**

But on concurrent request when Same **User** object need by multiple UserInfo, not able to load User object, even after saving this.

ServiceLayer method **saveUserAndInfo** are as below:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
@Override
public void saveUserAndInfo(String tenantName) throws Exception {

    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Name - " + tenantName + " - "
            + System.currentTimeMillis());


    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.setAddress("India - " + tenantName + " - "
            + System.currentTimeMillis());
    Set<UserInfo> setUserInfos = new HashSet<UserInfo>();
    setUserInfos.add(userInfo);

    user.setIdUser(1);

    user = findByCriteria(user);
    userInfo.setUser(user);

    saveUserInfo(userInfo);
}

/**
 * This method will return <code>User</code> object in persistent state, 
 * 
 * If exist fetch from DB, it NOT then insert and again fetch from db 
 * @param user
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public User findByCriteria(User user) throws Exception {

    List<Criterion> criterionList = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
    criterionList.add(Restrictions.eq("idUser", user.getIdUser()));

    Criteria crit = openSession().createCriteria(User.class);

    for (Criterion c : criterionList) {
        crit.add(c);
    }
    List<User> entityList = null;
    try {
        entityList = crit.list();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (entityList == null || entityList.isEmpty()) {
        log.error("No User Found - " + user.getIdUser() + " now adding...");
        saveUser(user);
        try {
            crit = openSession().createCriteria(User.class);
            entityList = crit.list();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (entityList != null && !entityList.isEmpty()) 
            return entityList.get(0);
        else {
            log.error("No User Found - " + user.getIdUser() + " Even after adding");
            throw new Exception("No User Found - " + user.getIdUser() + " Even after adding");
        }
    }
    else {
        return entityList.get(0);
    }
}
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: Read the javadoc os Session.get() (which would be much easier to use that using a criteria query), and tell us what you mean by "not able to load User object". What happens? Where? If you get an exception, post its stack trace. Otherwise, tell us what the problem is. What do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: **not able to load User object** means **NOT** able to fetch from DB (because `entityList` is coming null Or empty even after saving)


**some times** gets below exceptions on `saveUser(user);`:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: **some times** `saveUser(user);` runs without exceptions but when try to fetch from DB list returns as null or empty. please see above `public User findByCriteria(User user) throws Exception` method.